# Maven dependency not found in classpath in jenkins plugin

Tags: java, apache, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to add skip certificate checks for https requests in my plugin for development tests, for that I use http-components httpClient artifact version 4.x

Seems like every API call will compile fine, but during runtime I always get errors similar to this one:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
```

How can I solve this issue and make other java program (Jenkins) who uses my plugin, to avoid such thing from happening?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java - you are probably missing Apache HttpClient JAR file in your Jenkins' classpath.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek You are right. I checked the command params and indeed the classpath is missing the httpclient-4.4.jar. How is that supposed to work with dependencies? My plugin is dependant on this lib, and if I run tests I see the classpath contains its as expected, but Other programs using my code as a lib (Jenkins) won't bring the necessary deps. What is the common behavior for such case?

Comment: How is the httpclient dependency defined in pom.xml? Isn't it with the scope `provided`.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I didn't specify the scope. The default is compile

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the apache-http-client library is not on your calss path - the exception suggests that. Hence, this is unrelated to the ignoring of client verification

Comment: You are correct. I misunderstood it at start. I edited my question